# Is there a way to generate hierarchical output on a Directed Graph using NetworkX?

Tags: python, networkx

I'm trying to generate a hierarchical graph on a DIRECTED GRAPH.

By using this code:

```
   #Some code...

   def split_class(self):

        G = nx.DiGraph()
        for parents in self.Dependency_Hierarchy.keys():
            G.add_node(parents)
            for fields in self.Dependency_Hierarchy[parents]['fields'].keys():
                G.add_node(fields)
                G.add_edge(parents, fields)
            for methods in self.Dependency_Hierarchy[parents]['methods'].keys():
                G.add_node(methods)
                G.add_edge(parents,methods)
            for subclasses in self.Dependency_Hierarchy[parents]['subclasses'].items():
                G.add_edge(parents, subclasses[0])
            for methods in self.Dependency_Hierarchy[parents]['methods'].keys():
                 for callee in self.Dependency_Hierarchy[parents]['methods'][methods]:
                     G.add_edge(methods,callee)
            for fields in self.Dependency_Hierarchy[parents]['fields'].keys():
                for callee in self.Dependency_Hierarchy[parents]['fields'][fields]:
                    G.add_edge(fields, callee)

        pos = nx.kamada_kawai_layout(G)

        nx.draw(g,
                 with_labels=True,
                 node_size=500,
                 node_color="c",
                 pos=pos,
                 )
```

> Consider the Dependency_Hierarchy is:
>
> {'c0': {'fields': {'f0': ['m0', 'm1'], 'f1': ['m2', 'm3'], 'f2': ['m4']}, 'methods': {'m0': [], 'm1': [], 'm2': [], 'm3': [], 'm4': ['m6'], 'm5': []}, 'subclasses': {'c1': []}}, 'c1': {'fields': {}, 'methods': {'m6': []}, 'subclasses': {}}}

This graph is generated:

[image]

But what I need, is something like this:

[image]

There are two issues:

1. Set levels for each type of nodes (including c, f and m)
2. set colors for each type of nodes (including c, f and m)

Is there any way to generate a directed graph like that?

Comment: The graphviz layouts 'neato' or 'dot' should give you a hierarchical layout:`pos = nx.nx_agraph.graphviz_layout(G, prog='neato')`. Documentation [here](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable//reference/generated/networkx.drawing.nx_agraph.graphviz_layout.html). You can specify levels via the `args` argument but you would need to look up the specific graphviz instructions. However, in a dot or neato layout, all but your c0 and m6 would probably end up in the correct place as per your drawing (c0 and m6 would drop a layer). Node colors are specified via the node_colors argument to networkx.